# Application not getting data after build aap using phonegap build

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I have build my phone gap app using jquery I have get data using rest service. I have write ajax call as follows:----

```
var Products = function () {
var targetElement = $("product-list");
var content = 'No products found';
var url = API + "Products";
customerId = 1;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: url,
data: '{"Key":"' + Key + '","storeId":"' + 1+ '","languageId":"' + 1+ '","customerId":"' + customerId + '","currencyId":"' + 1+ '"}',
cache: true,
async: true,
complete: function (data) {
if (data == "undefined") {
targetElement.html(content);
$(".loader").hide();
return;
}
var resData = JSON.parse(data);
},
error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
targetElement.html(content);
}
});
};
```

when I run my application on local I got data but when I build using phonegap build its return me undefined. so there would be problem while build so can you tell me what you have changed so I can change as per. or what thing should be probable missed. Give responce as soon as possible.

in above code key is 20 random character string. & Api is a string or rest service url from where I got data in json format. and I got that data using this ajax call.

and I have include a whitelist or whitelist-legacy plugin and the domain whitelisting.
and also I have given all plugin to source to npm. and also write to get data from any domain or source I write below give code in cofig.xml file.

```
<access origin="*"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" source="npm"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
```

Comment: Does my answer helped you or is there still a problem with the ajax call?

Comment: @bjoerg thanx for your answer after posting this question i have solve issue by myself by adding <gap: plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" source="npm"/> this line but you give me perfact content or may i got issue to in ios build i will refers your answer or put this so i cannot get issue. so once again thanx for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cordova 5, it is required to set the Content-Security-Policy meta tag inside the index.html.

If you want from the iOS app connect to https://vatsal.ap.net for example, you have to add it at "gap:" part:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://vatsal.ap.net https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;">
```

See further documentation [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) at the bottom.

Hope it helps!